# Use Proxy Server with BigQueryClient C#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

How can I use a proxy server with the BigQueryClient ?

Here's a sample code :-

```
var fs = new FileStream(_BQConn.JSONKeyFileName, FileMode.Open);
GoogleCredential googlecreds = GoogleCredential.FromStream(fs);
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(_BQConn.ProjectId, googlecreds);
Task<BigQueryResults> TaskData = client.ExecuteQueryAsync(Query,null,null , null);
BigQueryResults data = await TaskData;
```